# Proof by Induction - Triangles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Given n non-parallel lines such that no three intersect at a point, there are n choose 3 triangles formed.

So far what I come up with is by using proof by induction:

```
Base Case: For every three lines a triangle is formed. 
Inductive Hypothesis: Assume true for k line.  
Inductive Step: Suppose that it holds for k lines, show true for k+1 lines.
```

But how do I show true for k+1 lines? Did I make a mistake in what I have in my induction proof so far? Any help is appreciated, and I don't need a direct solution, just how to begin will suffice.

Comment: Your problem seems tautological.  3 non-parallel lines that do not intersect in a point will form a triangle.  There are n choose 3 ways to choose 3 lines out of n.  So there will be n choose 3 triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was a homework assignment in a class trying to teach induction, you should complain.  You wrote already the main point: For every three lines, there is a triangle formed.  The converse, of course, is also true: for every triangle formed, there are three lines.  This establishes a bijection between $\{$triangles$\}$ and $\{$unordered triples of lines$\}$.  But the number of unordered triples of elements from an $n$-element set (in this case the set of lines) is precisely $\binom n 3$ — this is the definition "choose".

The reason I could imagine this being assigned in a class on induction is that it's not uncommon to use stupid *definitions* (they are not stupid, but rather important and deep, as facts, but should not be taken as the definition) of binomial coefficients.  Two *facts*, sometimes taken as definitions, are that $\binom n 3 = \frac16 n^3 - \frac12 n^2 + \frac13 n$, and that $\binom{n+1}3 = \binom n 3 + \binom n 2$.  Although both of these can be proved by induction, the most natural proofs are not inductive.  In any case, I could imagine an instructor looking for an argument like: by induction, there are $\binom n 3$ triangles formed from $n$ lines; adding another line creates a triangle for each of intersection among the original lines; there are $\binom n 2$ such intersections (why? by induction there there are $\binom n 2$ intersections among $n$ lines, and adding a line creates $n$ new intersections, and $\binom n 2 + n = \binom {n+1}2$); therefore there are $\binom n 3 + \binom n 2 = \binom{n+1}3$ triangles formed from $n+1$ lines.

But that inductive argument is stupid compared to the one-line argument that triangles correspond to triples.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great so far, yes this is exactly right.

Suppose it holds for $k$ lines and we have $k+1$ lines. Take out any one of these lines and make it special say line $L$.

Now by your inductive hypothesis there are ${k \choose 3}$ triangles formed that do not use the line $L$ at all.

So now you just have to count how many triangles use line $L$. To do this you should note that you need two more lines to make a triangle, but I won't spoil all the fun.